# Java DecimalFormat, # still displaying 0

Tags: java, decimalformat

My code looks like:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
return Double.parseDouble(df.format(sum));
```

Sum is a double, and when it equals 2, it is returning 2.0.
Is this because of how I have my formatting or because of how DecimalFormat is returning a string and I am converting it back to a double?

EDIT: The method I am using requires a double to be returned

Comment: With just one #, it still returns 2.0.

Comment: Once you've converted it from a double back to, uh, a double, it will have the value 2.0. Are you trying to convert it to a string without a trailing zero?

Comment: No, I would prefer to keep it as a double, but DecimalFormat converts it to a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to print out the `String` returned by `df.format(sum)`, then you would get:

```
2
```

Presumably you're printing the `double` returned by your method, which will always print at least one decimal place:

```
2.0
```

The numbers themselves don't have any intrinsic formatting.  To control the formatting, use `df.format(sum)` and print the `String`.  There no need to parse it back to a `double`, which would intentionally lose the formatting you just applied.

Comment: The method I am using however needs to return a double, and the double needs to be terminated to two decimal points. Sorry, I should have included that in my original post.

Comment: Then return the `double` from the method without using `DecimalFormat` at all.  The caller of this method can use a `DecimalFormat` to format the `double` into a `String` and output that `String`.

Comment: So in that case you will terminate 2.446 to 2.45 but 2.00 will stay 2.00... just the way numbers work

Comment: Yea, I see my problem now. I need to format it when I am calling the method, not in the method. Thanks!